# Dropzone.js - How to attach clickable (upload button) dynamically

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

Using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) for drag'n'drop file upload, I would like to attach a file upload button dynamically.

The page has a list of orders. When you select an order it is loaded through an Ajax call and shown. I instantiate Dropzone on the document.body at page load, in order to refuse uploads with a friendly error message until an order has been selected. When an order has been loaded an upload button is rendered with the order, and I would like to attach the Dropzone click handler to this dynamically created button. The button will be recreated every time a new order is selected.

I just can't seem to figure out how to set/change the `clickable` Dropzone option after the Dropzone has been created.

```
var documentDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, {
  url: '/path/to/upload.php',
  clickable: false,
  init: function() {
    this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
      var order_id = parseInt($('#dropzone_order_id').val(), 10);
      formData.append('order_id', order_id);
    });
  },
  accept: function(file, done) {
    if (parseInt($('#dropzone_order_id').val(), 10)) done();
    else {
      showErrorMessage('Please select an order first');
      done('error');
    }
  },
  success: function(file, response) {
    // handle response
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.view-opener', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#view-order').remove();
  var view = $('<div id="view-order"></div>')
    .prependTo('#inner-container-top');
  view.load(this.href, function(){

    // This is the failing line of code. The #dropzone-click-target 
    // is a button that is loaded with this ajax call.
    // (It also contains a hidden input with #dropzone_order_id 
    // which enables the upload functionality.)
    Dropzone(document.body, {clickable: '#dropzone-click-target'});

  });
});
```

A fiddle is available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tomas_eklund/761qr3r5/

Comment: Have you tried setting `autoProcessQueue` to false and then running `processQueue` in your custom click handler?

Comment: @elzi I don't think that would accomplish my goals. The reason I am instantiating Dropzone before an order is selected is because I want to gracefully handle situations where the user accidentally drops a file onto the window before selecting an order. For many file types, such as PDF, it will most probably be displayed by the browser and replace the current screen, which could be disastrous if there's plenty of unsaved data on the screen. I do not want to enqueue files and have them all uploaded onto the next selected order. I want to refuse the upload.

Comment: I see. I tried messing around with it for a bit, changing `    myDropzone.options.clickable = true;` after the fruit selection, but doing that alone does not set up the event listeners. I would poke around Dropzones code and look for the `if ( clickable)` to see what's run. You could do a hacky solution by overwriting the vent listener initially, then unbinding it after selecting a fruit.

Comment: @elzi Thanks, you spurred me into actually digging into the source code (something I actively had tried to avoid) and found a "solution". The `init()` method of the Dropzone object will set up the click handlers and the `clickableElements` array was actually made public.

Comment: Well done! I was pretty sure that would lead to the right solution. You should make a pull request on their git repo if you come up with an elegant solution.

Comment: @elzi Actually, not so well done it seems. In the simple fiddle, which never actually uploads anything, I never noticed that my previous code was seriously flawed. Calling the `init()` method again (I assume it's called by the constructor too) made it so that every file was uploaded twice, with each upload POST containing two order_id parameters. In addition to this the `success` event was fired twice per upload. A complete mess. The new solution (see edited answer) seems to work better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By scanning the dropzone.js source code I found an undocumented `destroy()` method. Using this in conjunction with a reusable options object I am now destroying and recreating the Dropzone for each new order loaded.

So on page load I create this Dropzone (that will not upload anything but refuse all uploads gracefully):

```
var dropzoneOptions = { clickable: false /* see Question ... */ };
var documentDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, dropzoneOptions);
```

Inside my ".view-opener" click handler, after the ajax call that loads the selected order, I've added this code that will destroy the previous Dropzone object, augment the options object and create a new Dropzone instance:

```
documentDropzone.destroy();
dropzoneOptions.clickable = '#dropzone-click-target';
documentDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, dropzoneOptions);
```

I've also updated the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tomas_eklund/761qr3r5/39/

Comment: This helped me! Thanks!

Comment: @TomasEklund, how can you set image thumbnail to that clickable, let's say have two clickable div elements, and thumbnail appear on one that was clicked to browse the file? thanks

Comment: @HouyNarun I'm afraid I don't understand the question. You would probably be better off posting your query as a new question here on the forums. Include a fiddle so that we can see what you are doing.